# Hiding a div without messing up the layout

Tags: html, layout

I have a div on which I add contents dynamically and after all the contents are added to it I am converting the entire div to an Image through canvas. During this entire time the hidden div is not shown but exists at the background. My problem is that I can only convert that hidden div to image if the attribute "visibility" is set to "hidden". If I set "display" as "none" then I can't draw the image to the canvas. And since I can not do display:none; my whole layout is messed up.

Can anyone suggest me what I should do so that my layout is unaffected and I still have the div somewhere at the background hidden so that I can add contents to it dynamically and later convert to an image? I appreciate the help.

My hidden div

```
<div class="temp" style="visibility:hidden;">
  <div id="finalimage">
  </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#preview").click(function () {
      var extra_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var finaldivheight = $("#finalimage").css('height');
      var finaldivwidth = $("#finalimage").css('width');
      extra_canvas.setAttribute('width', 1013);
      extra_canvas.setAttribute('height', 460);
      html2canvas($('#finalimage'), {

            onrendered: function (canvas) {

                var ctx = extra_canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, widthhalf, heighthalf);
                var dataURL = extra_canvas.toDataURL();
                sendImg = extra_canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

                var img = $(document.createElement('img'));
                img.attr('src', dataURL);

                img.attr('width', '100%');
                img.attr('height', 'auto');
                $('#secondfinal').html(img);

                //secondfinal div is inside the Modal and thats what I am previewing
                $("#myModal").modal("show");

            }

        });
    }
    }
```

Comment: Could you perform your manipulation in JavaScript before your div is appended to the DOM so it is never hidden?  Can you post some code?

Comment: I updated the question. On the other note I also tried deleting the div entirely after it is converted to an image but for some reason the modal doesn't show up when I do that. Maybe because the image conversion process takes some time????